# display inline-block not applying

Tags: css, display

I am trying to align the first two divs inside "product-details" class. I removed the last div with clear:both; I gave 150px width to the first div with class "text-center".I gave display:inline-block and position:relative to both of the first divs. I made width of the second div auto.

When I check the computed values in the inspect element the first div is not accepting the display:inline-block. It shows display:block; and the two divs are not aligned horizontally. I have had this situation before also.

```css
div.text-center {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-details">
  <div class="text-center">...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

div.text-center is not taking display inline-block instead shows display block in the element inspector

Comment: Your code snippet works fine for me...

Comment: Will adding a `float: left;` to your first div help you achieve what you want?

Answer (score 1):

The code does work. I right clicked on the second ... and clicked inspect element. You can see in the "Elements" tab then in the "Styles" tab that the default display: block was overridden by display: inline-block. What browser are you using? This is on the latest version of Chrome that I am getting this result.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out above, the code should work. You can try and force it to work by adding an important rule
`div.text-center {display: inline-block !important;}`

Answer (score 0):

I removed floats and display changes from block to inline-block as required. That was the only option. Also I need to remove width auto and give width in % for both divs to align them horizontally. This was the solution I found. Thanks for your answers.